# Top alignment for FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm using a `FlowLayout` `JPanel`. The panel looks ugly when child component heights are different. I'm looking for a solution to make them top-align (similar to `valign="top"` with table cells in HTML).

Comment: Have you taken a look at MigLayout?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I realize this question was asked over a year ago, but like me, I thought many would stumble across this forum post and be left attempting to make a workaround like that one suggested in the bug report (failed to work for me just fyi).

Either way there is a better answer since JDK 1.6.  Flowlayout has the following method:

```
public void setAlignOnBaseline(boolean alignOnBaseline)
```

If you use this method on your flowlayout and set it to true, then when flowlayout lays out the components it will check each component's baseline and align the component along this baseline.

But that's not all you need to do.

The component in question must override the following two methods in this way:

```
@Override
public Component.BaselineResizeBehavior getBaselineResizeBehavior() {
    return Component.BaselineResizeBehavior.CONSTANT_ASCENT;
}

@Override
public int getBaseline(int width, int height) {
    return 0;
}
```

They are methods in JComponent and layouts and layoutmanagers use these methods to determine how to layout the component.

If you take the steps mentioned above all the components will align themselves along the top of each row.  Of course if you just want to use a component like JButton you will obviously have to extend it in order to achieve your desired goal... but it's not as much work as overriding layoutcontainer with a workaround that you have to debug.  At least I think so.

Good luck,
-Asaf

Comment: +1. The workaround did not work for me either, but I think that's because it exists for a different purpose. As it is stated in the bug report: *"The three vertical alignment options would be top, center, and bottom. **It would lay things out exactly the same way,** but drop the components to the middle or the bottom of the panel".*

Answer (score 1):

Someone else has wished for this, in the form of a bug-report (which also lists a workaround).

Have a look at

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4295966

Comment: Actually this bug report has a different purpose: *"Please add an option to the flow layout to let me specify the vertical alignment. The three vertical alignment options would be top, center, and bottom. **It would lay things out exactly the same way,** but drop the components to the middle or the bottom of the panel."* So the link's workaround makes it possible to choose between three options for vertical placement of the components (FlowLayout always puts them at the top) but they will still be center-aligned with each other in case they have different heights. Just pointing out...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a BoxLayout. It supports vertical alignment. The only problem is you need to manually insert horizontal strut components.

Or you could try using the [Relative Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). In your case you would use:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.X_AXIS, 5);
rl.setBorderGap(5);
rl.setAlignment(RelativeLayout.LEADING);
JPanel panel = new JPanel( rl );
panel.add(...);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I gave you two suggestions and both work. Did you read the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Box Layout"? If you need more help post your SSCCE: http://sscce.org

Comment: Finally, I extended the FlowLayout to make it work as I want and it's kinda cool now: only expand the width :D Thank you very much